# Why is my code faster when running with Performance Analysis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got a bit of a conundrum here. I have been trying to speed up a certain function, now when I run my application it takes ~16-17 seconds to run this function.

Now if I run the same with Performance Analysis running alongside it in VS2010, in order to find the slower sections, the code executes in ~6-7 seconds. Now, if my code did run this fast, that would be perfectly acceptable for the application.

I've tried running the code (without perf analysis) via both debug and release profiles, with little to no difference.

Anyone got any ideas what may be occurring here?

Few notes: the function in question uses quite a lot of LINQ to SQL and the performance analysis im using is CPU Sampling.

Comment: Heisenbug.  Do you get the same 16-17 seconds if you compile in release mode (versus debug)?

Comment: And did you run the program outside of VS? Simply running a program in VS with the debugger attached disables a lot of jitter optimizations.

Comment: Robaticus, yes (as stated). CodeInChaos - I do notice a big difference between outside and inside VS, yes, but I was expecting that.

Comment: Actually, I think from the answers given here I've probably got the answer: Performance Analysis probably compiles the application, then runs the process outside of VS (without the container/vhost) and attaches itself to the actual process - thus removing all the VS overhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should focus on the slowest parts of your code and optimize them anyway if you identify what takes longer than other parts, don't care of the absolute duration in seconds but just think relative.

Even if you see the whole application is executed in 7 seconds, if there are methods which take 40% of this whole time try to optimize them then you will surely profit of this fine tuning even without Performance Analysis enabled and the total execution time will drop even more if initially it was around 17 seconds.

Comment: +1 for the advice,  You could better spend time in optimising than researching why the time difference.

Comment: Well yes, but the problem was that it's perfectly optimized "within" the analysis but not outside.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see a lot of dll's being loaded as you enter the function in the non performance analysis case?  I wonder if entering this function is causing a lot of dlls to load, that in the performance analysis case have already been loaded earlier.

Comment: Not really, no - or at least nothing unsual

Comment: Add trace statements to your function with a date time stamp and try to narrow down where the slow down is happening, where is the 16-17 seconds coming from, check the time write before the function call, and then right as you enter, be liberal right now, because it sounds like your going to have to do your performance analysis the old fashioned way.

Comment: Well, I have managed to locate the problem - and fixed it, but the question was aimed at "why" the problem occurred rather than how to get around such a problem

Comment: What was the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: The problem itself wouldn't be relevant here - just a stupid mistake wherein I was doing way too much conversions due to some DBML code not understanding whether something was a decimal or not. The actual issue here, I only have a theory about - see the original qestion for that.